# Cannot mark question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The question
[VS2013 Load Test with Multiple Users that requires login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842853/vs2013-load-test-with-multiple-users-that-requires-login) 
has just been asked. It appears to appears to be a duplicate of
[How to use a list of values for a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649732/how-to-use-a-list-of-values-for-a-parameter/23673194#23673194) so I attempted to close the new question as a duplicate. The attempt to close was refused with the message:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

The referenced question is as the message states, but its asker has chosen not to acknowledge the answer in the nearly 8 months since it was asked.
Why is there this restriction on reporting duplicates?

The referenced question has an answer. The topic (ie load testing with visual studio) is a low traffic topic. Other posts here on meta refer to the amount of poor questions raised every day and encourage people to tidy up or vote to close them.

Comment: Why don't you first upvote the answer so the restriction can be removed ?

Comment: @BondedDust I tried that but it says I cannot vote on an answer that I wrote.

Comment: There, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

The restriction is there so that questions aren't closed as a duplicate of a post without the author of the duplicate getting an answer to their question.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Why is there this restriction on reporting duplicates?"*

They should lead to upvoted or accepted answers to be a useful feature.