# What is the right way for a user (not a mod) to handle duplicate questions from the one user where neither has been (nor will be) answered?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

**Can someone please explain**, with respect to a flag for [problem in download and read generated excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384536/problem-in-download-and-read-generated-excel-file):

[image: Declined flag]

I think a question posted twice by the same user (at least according to Mark Baker, nearly four years ago: *possible duplicate of problem in download and read generated excel file*). Separately, Juhana has written *possible duplicate of How to suppress the file corrupt warning at excel download?* (that posted by a different user – and has an accepted answer).

Normal users can’t VTC either since neither has an accepted answer (even with my dupe hammer) – which is not really any wonder since the OP has mentioned *I found the solution*. 
Is it this [The restriction is there so that questions aren't closed as a duplicate of a post without the author of the duplicate getting an answer to their question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/282999/1505120)?

I suppose enough downvotes (meta effect?) might eventually get one or another closed/deleted but is the message that mods are too busy to bother about the same user posting the same question repeatedly or am I missing what the “proper procedure” is in a case like this (just let them fester?)?

Comment: Downvote, comment, move on. You can also solicit downvote requests in a chatroom. Let the user know that once they reach a score of 75 they can set a bounty on their question to attract more attention.

Answer (score 1):

You should explain in your flag why a mod action is necessary. A normal duplicate is *not* a matter to call in mods about, you should use close votes instead. There's nothing in your mod message that says that the post you're linking to has issues you can't deal with without extra powers.

Explain the situation, saying that you think this is an exact dup created by the same user with two different accounts, and that neither question has answers, preventing ordinary duplicate close votes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with reviews, not the same context at all. You're asking someone to do work here. And if you've already spent the time analyzing the situation, why ask someone else to spend that time again re-analyzing it? Don't waste mod's time.

Comment: Whether you see it as that or not, reality is that when you cast a custom flag, someone has to do something to handle it - i.e., you're asking someone to do some work. You cast a flag that looks identical to a normal close vote. I suspect mods get a lot of those: custom flags when canned flags/votes should have been used, hence quick rejection in most cases as a way of "education". Give them the information you found up front to avoid wasting both your time and theirs.