# Flagging a post as a duplicate should cost reputation points

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions, reputation, vote-to-close

As of now one of the ways to perform a point-free aggressive action against a poster is to flag the post as a duplicate leaving one more avenue that opens the system to abuse. There should be a speed-bump placed in the way of flagging questions as duplicate to force a bit of thoughtful consideration as to the validity of the duplicate -- which in many cases is open to interpretation.

I acknowledge that there is a quorum established for closure, however, regardless of closure the question is still marked as duplicate which can be seen as rewarding a would-be malicious user. The speed-bump I propose is to **make the initial dupe-flag cost one or two points**. This will stop the potential for a large portion of unwarranted random dupe-flagging, but not prevent valid dupe-flagging by thoughtful users who are concerned about the quality of questions.

Comment: Didn't we already do this?

Comment: And you try it again?? I believe there's already a FR to **award points** for successfully closed dupes.

Comment: @Don'tPanic there was a previous question (now closed) that contained this feature request. I isolated here in its narrowed scope.

Comment: Yeah, I recall there are folks wanting to *reward* finding duplicates.  I suppose I'm confused as to what you think this would address.  What dupe closures have you seen that were truly unwarranted to a scale to demand development action to address this?

Comment: Closing as duplicate is not an aggressive action against a poster.

Comment: People don't randomly dupe-flag.

Comment: Is the initial flag random? What if the user casting it knows it's a dupe and is doing exactly what they should be doing - closing a duplicate question?

Comment: We're not going to penalize users by removing reputation for flagging or closing posts as a duplicate. If a question is not a duplicate, then it won't be closed or it will be reopened.

Comment: Here we go again. The people who disagree with you are "Aggressive", "abuse", "malicious", the ones that agree with you are "thoughtful users", "concerned about the quality of questions". Ridiculous, again.

Comment: I'm tempted of marking this as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates) other better idea... But I wont do it for free!

Comment: This didn't go well [the last time you proposed this, just 2 days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355735/how-general-does-a-question-answer-need-to-be-to-be-regarded-as-a-duplicate). What makes you think the community is more receptive this time round? You have failed to even begin to build a case as to why this is needed. Can you please provide some form of **concrete proof** that a large number of posts are unjustly (even randomly) being flagged as duplicates, to the detriment of the site?

Comment: @MartijnPieters if the accepted answer given by yivi at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280568/reward-for-close-voters-finding-appropriate-duplicates did not see the need to provide statistical evidence, neither do I. He and I give prima facie evidence that the system is open to abuse. My prima facie is more direct however. please read the first line of my post.

Comment: @misspeller: if you actually see an abusive duplicate flag, you *flag the post for moderator attention*. We have other avenues for abuse, and it's almost always trivially solved by having the moderators deal with the abuse. Now, unless you have evidence that this problem is widespread, we are not going to put a speedbump before users help keep the site tidy.

Comment: In that case, why not reward potential abusers? Again same principle as as in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280653/2066936

Comment: @misspeller: "Potential abusers" are irrelevant. The only thing that matters are *actual* abusers. Until "potential" becomes "actual", the matter is moot.

Comment: @misspeller _"prima facie"_ Quiquid latine dictum sit altum videtur.  Doesn't always work of course :-P ...

Comment: Do we really have to discuss this daily now?

Comment: Could you please provide examples of duplicates that shouldn't be marked as duplicates (and show they're the majority)? **Everyday** I see lots of dupes, and I've seen no abuse at all: most are really dupes, some are "kinda" (because they're very similar, but not exactly the same), and just a few aren't (and are usually reopened). You seem to have a different impression (that most dupes are invalid/erroneous), so the best way to not rely on individual impressions is to [check the facts](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/645804/questions-marked-as-duplicates). Please do so.

Comment: You can _say_ it, but as usual you can't and won't _prove_ it. Nothing to see here folks, move along :)

Comment: Actually, we all have access to [some data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/645804/questions-marked-as-duplicates) - I believe that's enough for an initial investigation. And as the others already said, you can flag abuses to moderators.

Comment: @misspeller _"I have witness abuse of this feature"_ Because some of _your_ questions were closed as duplicates?

Comment: It's hard to prove intent. All we can do is deal with the loop-holes, of which I argue this is one.

Comment: @Hugo I'm not a very active user. However, I can say in my experience I have received the impression that some have abused this feature.

Comment: @Hugo OP is here for an argument, nothing more. Providing proof, or more realistically admitting that there isn't any, would help this to come a conclusion, which they don't want.

Comment: @misspeller: "*It's hard to prove intent. All we can do is deal with the loop-holes, of which I argue this is one.*" It's hard to believe you when you're on record as saying that you believe closing *any question* as a duplicate is "insulting to the user unless they clearly consent". Since you believe that maintenance of our site constitutes de-facto aggression, it's kind of hard not to see your suggestion as a way to get people to stop doing something you don't think they should be doing, rather than a genuine effort to stop real, harmful abuse.

Comment: @NicolBolas well one can argue that it is aggressive, "We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A; system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn’t matter if there are questions at all, does it?" ([Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/))

Comment: @gnat "aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions" is not an agressive action _against the poster_, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic agree, especially if you take into account that end goal of this is to help other askers (those who ask worthy and interesting questions) get answers. "Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn’t matter if there are questions at all, does it?"

Comment: You know, as someone who dupe closes a fair bit, I'd actually be fine with a point or two for a mistaken closure, _provided the asker also has something on the line_. But I really don't think it would be worthwhile. All this nonsense about it being malicious and aggressive is offensive, though.

Comment: " the only way to perform a point-free aggressive action against a poster is to flag the post" This is not correct. Downvoting a question is also a 'point-free' action for me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm actually not as offended by the mistaken notion that I vote to close questions as duplicates because I'm malicious and aggressive as I am by the implication that if I _was_ malicious and aggressive, voting to close questions on Stack Overflow would be the best thing I could come up with.

Comment: @TylerH but still, not an aggressive action against the poster.

Comment: If, for some reason, this 'speed-bump' was implemented on a trial basis, what metric do you suggest to measure efficacy in reducing the alleged 'unwarranted random dupe-flagging'?   You know that 'real' speed-bumps are largely ineffective or actually counter-productive right?  SUV's with good suspension travel just don't slow down, and those with high-power cars make up the time lost in braking by accelerating to more-lethal speeds in between the bumps.  I suspect that your '2 rep for dup vote' measure would be equally effective:(

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes.  Getting drunk and starting a bar fight would seem more productive than sitting at a computer, looking for random people to annoy.

Comment: @TylerH so that's where all these downvotes I'm receiving are coming from...>10K users. I'll have to add new a feature request to remedy that.

Comment: No! We petty 2k users are downvoting as well!! Don't exclude us from the action!

Comment: @misspeller _"so that's where all these downvotes I'm receiving are coming from...>10K users."_ Downvoting questions is free for everyone.

Comment: @user0042 ok, I thought we were talking the main site.

Comment: @misspeller you've invoked the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) this is the result when you do that with a poor question.

Comment: @misspeller: "*so that's where all these downvotes I'm receiving are coming from...>10K users*" I'm curious how you *know* that these votes are "coming from... >10K users". Since voting is anonymous, either you've managed to hack the system or you're making claims without evidence. Which is it?

Comment: @misspeller No, any user can downvote a question without any point cost. Downvoting an answer costs the downvoter 1 reputation, while downvoting a question costs the downvoter none.

Comment: @NicolBolas he probably took my "for me" phrase to mean "for me as a 10k+ user"

Comment: Another 'inhibit dup flags' meta post:(   Massively downvoted, again.  You should give up - you're flagging a dead horse.

Comment: seem to remember it costing two points. Something must have changed.

Comment: Ok, my bad. The premise of this post is therefore incorrect. I.e. I have learned that there are multiple ways to cause harm with impunity. You may now delete this post.

Comment: "I have learned that there are multiple ways to cause harm with impunity." Or as most other regulars would say "The system doesn't penalize users who are trying to maintain the quality standards."

Comment: @misspeller If **you** downvote a **question**, **you** don't lose rep (the **user who posted the question** loses 2 rep). If you downvote an **answer**, though, you lose 1 rep (and the user who posted the answer loses 2 rep): https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: But if we delete this question, then how are we supposed to aggressively insult all of the users who propose this same feature at some point in the future by closing their question as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @Keiwan I'm sure you'll find a way.

Comment: So, again..... "I will complain and thrash about how the site is handled because I KNOW THE SITE AND I KNOW HOW IT SHOULD B..... oh wait, I didn't know THIS is how it worked". Funny how often these outlandish suggestions come from people who don't truly understand how the site works... ALMOST as if the community knew what it was doing...

Comment: Ok. Mea culpa. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: You seem to be missing my main point. The issue isn't that you made a mistake, so fixing it isn't that relevant. The issue is that if you don't fully understand the site, a lot of the ideas you have might be tainted by your misunderstandings.

Comment: Oh I understand the site's premise based on the article @gnat pointed to about sand and pearls. I simply disagree with that premise. I think "pearls" are overrated. Users aren't looking for a well-written beautiful document, they are looking for a quick answer to their difficult problem. They want a one-liner not an exposition. Google understands this dichotomy. They charge for answers (search results) not for questions (search queries).

Comment: So... You think the main reason and goal of this site is overrated... Brings back the question I asked you ytd then: why stay here? You seem to disagree with the stance of this site... Staying here is just asking to be aggravated at this point.

Comment: Great.  SO isn't Google, and isn't trying to be.  We're here to build a long lasting, high quality repository of knowledge.  If all a user wants is a quick answer to their unresearched crappy homework question, then duping that is doing them a favor instead of unceremoniously deleting it.

Comment: yes, but dupes ultimately get deleted, or that's the idea anyway.

Comment: For low quality questions that serve no purpose, that's a *good* thing.  It cleans up the junk.  For those that did their research and didn't find their answer, those stick around, as they serve as signposts to help others find the same answer.

Comment: ok, back to the old identity crisis: what comes first at S.O. help the average developer or build up some unachievable "repository of knowledge" hint. they've tried this before. It doesn't work. Ever heard of the notion of the semantic web?

Comment: No crisis here; just a user who refuses to accept what SO is so successful at.

Comment: but dupes aren't "ultimately deleted" if they are good signposts. BAD signposts are deleted yes... good ones have NO reason of disappearing (hint: ever heard of StackOverflow? It's been PRETTY successful at building a repository of knowledge... you know, they ARE the biggest Q&A site by far while trying to go that goal)

Comment: Yeah, similar things were said about Yahoo around 1999ish.

Comment: Great. then start your own Q&A platform. You seem confident this one will crash. If you start yours now you may get the lift you need when Stack crashes.

Comment: Hey, S.O. is a great site. I'm not denying that. I'm just saying you guys took a wrong turn when you made it a official policy to "aggressively" go after your user base via downvoting and dupe-flagging.

Comment: The reason Stack is a great site (as opposed to, say Yahoo answers) is BECAUSE we moderate aggressively. Again, you see it as "against the user base" and not "for the content" which is what it is. Get rid of the ego, and that'll fare better. In any case I think it's clear by now your suggestions aren't in line with what the community thinks. So either prove your point to get a REAL discussion started, or realize you won't change that behavior you seem to loathe so much, and learn to live with it.

Comment: Has anyone checked for a significant amount of "unwarranted random dupe-flagging" yet? Or is it better left as an exercise to the OP?

Comment: Someone here must have complained because I have been banned from asking questions on S.O. I clicked to find out why, and it says "try rewriting all your questions" to improve their quality etc. Somehow I doubt the quality of my questions up until now has anything to do with why I have gotten banned. Anyway, guess it's just my luck. I'll get dupe-flagged anyway, like I always do.

Comment: *Someone here must have complained...* If you mean that someone explicitly asked that you be banned then no, that's not how question bans work. The ban algorithm is based on voting on your questions.

Comment: *"regardless of closure the question is still marked as duplicate"* What?

Comment: @misspeller Once again you're failing to know how the site works. [Question bans are automatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), regardless of people's complaints.

Comment: @Hugo well, misspeller may have been the target of some, umm... 'meta-driven, targeted question inspection, this resulting in negative voting beyond that which would normally be expected'.  Can't imagine why, go figure, (no it wasn't me).  That could result in a Q ban.

Comment: On the plus side, if you cannot post questions, you cannot have questions flagged as duplicate.

Comment: Nobody cares anymore, but today I flagged my first question _as duplicate_... and I must say it really rocks!

Comment: False duplicates nonetheless exist and I would welcome reputation taken away from people who falsely flagged something as duplicate, which was in the end resolved as a non-duplicate without further edits.

Answer (score 83):

> There should be a speed-bump placed in the way of flagging questions as duplicate to force a bit of thoughtful consideration as to the validity of the duplicate -- which in many cases is open to interpretation.

There is. You have to provide a link.

That's more of a speed bump than exists for any other close reason.

Comment: 15 minutes, 3 moderators active in a thread, why wasn't this yet another non constructive attempt to start a rant removed yet?

Comment: I'm on my phone doing other things and disinclined to put more effort into this question.

Comment: @BrakNicku - If we delete complaints about the site, we run the risk of looking like we're censoring dissenting opinions. Sometimes it's best to sit back and have the community counter the arguments being made. If things proceed on to trolling, insults, or otherwise get out of control, then we can step in.

Comment: @BradLarson I do not have access to deleted meta posts, but I think it's at least 3rd same post from the same user. Same result - tons of downvotes and a flame. Some users enjoy it and say it's time to watch and open popcorn, but could this bring anything constructive?

Comment: @BrakNicku if anything it is at least a refreshing topic instead of the *require a comment on down vote* ones. I'm out of popcorn ...

Comment: @rene that explains why you missed a chance to add highly upvoted comment this time

Comment: It's also nice to have dupe targets for this kind of complainggestion, so the flames die down a little faster next time around, @BrakNicku.

Comment: -1 disagree, link is not enough of a speed bump. I demand that there was  an upvoted or accepted answer at that link! [Oh wait...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282998/839601)

Answer (score 38):

Closing a question as a duplicate (usually) already imposes a reputation penalty.

Speaking from experience, in *many* cases, it would not only be quicker and easier to post an answer, but (as long as the question wasn't too spectacularly terrible) would be a lot more likely to gain up-votes. Linking a duplicate *can* gain a couple of up-votes, but on average you don't gain much (even if you provided the accepted answer to the question you linked).

Doing a quick calculation, it looks like when I vote to close a question as a duplicate (or close it single-handedly), I'm not only doing extra work, but also losing an average of around 40 points of reputation.

Comment: So... Duplicate closing is an "opportunity cost" but with rep... I like it!

Comment: Also, there's already a rep cost: You have to have oodles of it in order to be able to ban-hammer.

Comment: I would add that for dupehammers penalty should be even worse because when regular user votes it hangs for a while and other readers check their comment and link and some of them may vote. But when there is hammer vote it closes immediately so that only asker is interested in visiting and many askers don't even have enough rep for upvote. Add that for gold tag bagde holders it is by definition easy to answer in "their" tags and one starts wondering why they are so active in doing this ([stats here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346592/839601) say about 30K hammer closes in 90 days)...

Comment: ...I only can guess some sort of [intrinsic motivation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42481/165773) at work there: when they know that question has been already thoroughly answered elsewhere the fast and sure way to help asker is to redirect them to duplicate (yes this doesn't bring rep but this helps people)

Answer (score 17):

Your last post here was deleted, so I'm going to assume that you are referring to this question: *[How to check if I have write permissions to an Oracle table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803046/how-to-check-if-i-have-write-permissions-to-an-oracle-table)*

I think the below points apply here:

1. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service
2. Having multiple questions asking about the same thing is not helpful for future readers because there would be thousands of same questions with one small difference based on each situation.

> NOTE NOT A DUPLICATE. EVIDENCE: The suggested answer by mathguy does not contain the specific SQL that answers my question. There is no SQL found in that answer that specifically gives me a binary (e.g. yes/no) answer to whether I (first person) have access to a given table. FURTHERMORE, the duplicate question itself is ambiguous as to who (is it an admin or regular user?) is executing the SQL. That is why I specifically said "check my privileges" not check anyone's privileges.

It is a duplicate because the solution is the same for everyone, but it needs to be applied to your situation by you. Like mentioned already, most users here don't provide answers for users that have made no attempt to solve the problem as your original post shows.

> As of now the only way to perform a point-free aggressive action against a poster is to flag the post as a duplicate leaving the system open to abuse.

No, there are many flags and none of them deduce points, from users that are raising the flag, when used on questions. I would have flagged your question as "too broad" because you made no attempt.

> I acknowledge that there is a quorum established for closure, however, regardless of closure the question is still marked as duplicate which can be seen as **rewarding** a would-be malicious user.

No one gets a points reward for flagging. There are only some badges that can be earned. On the other hand, users can get a flag ban if they incorrectly flag too many posts.

Comment: Oh, they added that notice back.  How unfortunate.

Comment: "there are many flags and none of them deduce points" - [Spam and offensive flags cast automatic downvotes](/a/258456/5764553). The vote is removed if the flag is declined. Of course, the moderators will notice _pretty quick_ if you're abusing those flags.

Comment: @AndrewMyers downvotes on questions don't get a -1 in reputation, just on asnwers

Comment: But once more, _none_ of the various close vote reasons/flags are aggressive actions against the poster. _Downvoting_ is not an aggressive action against the poster. No one even cares who the poster is.

Comment: @tima Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying there. I thought you meant flags don't change the _OP's_ rep (as in, "quit worrying about people destroying your rep by flagging you").

Comment: @Don'tPanic "No one even cares who the poster is" Great. Now they can stop feeling injured and go back to being generally depressed...

Comment: @Don'tPanic 13 downvotes is however.

Comment: @YvetteColomb To what are you referring?

Comment: @DOn'tPanic the OP has been getting a LOT of downvotes on the main site after posting here. He is likely aggravating some people that take revenge on him by downvoting his main stuff. THAT is an aggressive behavior against him (and I assume what Yvette was alluding to)

Comment: @Don'tPanic to a downvoter/flagger given to a malicious nature, the poster may be anonymous but that doesn't make him/her less than a person.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hadn't visited the OP's profile. Yeah, revenge downvoting _is_ an aggressive action against the poster. It's inappropriate and childish, it's strongly discouraged here, and I'm sorry to hear that it's happening. But it's also not the normal case. I'm referring to the general case of people voting on content as they encounter it while normally browsing the site. They don't care who you are. They're just going to vote on the post.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yep I was referring to the linked question in this answer.

Comment: @Patrice yep that's what I was referring to - it's the meta effect and it's really childish as Don't Panic said.

Comment: Yes - in cases like this, where I 100% disagree with the OP, I will not even bother looking at their questions so I have a shield against 'revenge downvoting' allegations.  I don't like it, and I don't do it.