# Disable downvotes on questions that get answers

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes

Why on earth questions that get answered (often many answers) can also be down-voted?

If a question get answers it means that it is legitimate! So therefore I suggest a new feature request to disable downvotes on questions with answers.

Comment: So if someone comes in and asks 'why is the sky blue', and someone posts an answer, refraction of light becomes on topic for this site?

Comment: *"If a question get answers it means that it is legitimate"* - legitimate in what sense? "Answerable"? Most likely. "Shows research effort; it's useful and clear"? Not necessarily.

Comment: If he gets an answer then someone took it seriously !

Comment: @ronTLV but it doesnt make the question good or relevant or useful to others. So there are still reasons to downvote questions, even after they are answered. + we open ourselves to gaming the system with this rule (1. User opens bad question. 2. User uses sock puppet to post crap answer.  3. Suddenly crap question can't be downvoted.)

Comment: or it's just some bozo who needs to post some junk on the internet.

Comment: Crap questions can be flagged ! and this is why we dont need down-vote at all.

Comment: @RonTLV don't forget that editing a question can make others reverse the downvote and even upvote. Difficult to do with flagging/closing. Downvoting is more comprehensive and easily reversible.

Comment: @RonTLV crap questions that are on topic and just lack research shouldn't be flagged, but downvoted. How does THAT work in your system? And I am SURE mods don't have time to handle more 'this is a crap post by a sockpuppet trying to game the system, please handle it' type flags.

Comment: No! Rep crow prey on bad question! Go to the infamous tag and search for question with negative vote and unaccepted answer. And tell me You still want this!

Comment: No system Patrice - I just see that down-votes are excessively used. I think it's wrong.

Comment: *"Crap questions can be flagged ! "* No, they can't. Only certain types of crap can be flagged. The rest of the crap just has to be downvoted; there's no flag for it.

Comment: @RonTLV well if your new feature can't handle this.... It's not good. Anyway let's check a quick example from your profile... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41440137/query-from-datastore-to-android-application has an answer (a quasi link only answer). It's still a question with no research, no mcve, nothing useful per our standards. Because someone answered it with links... I can't triage the question and signal to others 'this isn't up to par to our standards, move along'? What benefit does your FR has, except make sure we have more bad stuff lying around?

Comment: And btw for that question, a cursory 'read data from datastore' search would have shown you db, ndb, & the Cloud Datastore API. From there you should have experimented and opened a more precise question.

Comment: @RonTLV you're relatively new here. Maybe you need to build up more experience in asking & answering before asking for such radical changes. (but you know that when ... you're not as new :) we all make mistakes at first, my first meta post was funny but utter crap: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333906/automatic-downvoting-bad-questions)

Comment: Take a simple question like [how to comment php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751294/how-to-comment-php-code) and tell me if you FR is valid on this one? (ps: I have a list of 200-300 question with this level of effort. i will give you one exemple every time you will say you still want the Feature)

Comment: @RonTLV I'm not sure where you base *I just see that down-votes are excessively used* on but [the data shows something different](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/717046#graph). Unless last month the world has changed dramatically ...

Comment: see also: [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252677/839601)

Comment: Thank you all ! that was an orchestrated response no doubt about it. I'm clicking That solved my problem !

Comment: @RonTLV orchestrated? no, more like a consensus.

Comment: @RonTLV not orchestrated... It just happens so often that a new user who doesn't really 'get' stack (yet) comes in with such a proposal, that the response CAN look rehearsed. We've just 'been there, done that' already

Comment: @RonTLV, I'm not a power user. I don't have rep. But still I can't see why you ask such Feature. Once you reach 500rep, spend one hour in review queue. You underestimate how bad it can be.

Comment: *down-votes are excessively used* - maybe because there are an excessive amount of bad questions to be downvoted. As @DragandDrop said, once you have enough rep to access the review queues, spend some time there and see it for yourself. The [daily limit in the number of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5212/352742) is not enough for that amount.

Comment: On a non-France, non-victual note, 'Crap questions can be flagged !' well, they could, but there are not enough resources in the universe to handle those many flags.  That's why a numeric value is attached to each Q&A to provide a measure of quality and that vote does not require the attention of a vast horde of moderators, (that thought is actually quite disturbing;).

Comment: ..and flags are binary.  What would I do if a Q or A was merely poor, or not optimal, as distinct from totally wrong?

Comment: The other thing is that any kind of relaxation of moderation opens a portal to the ninth level of hell.  Armies of vamps, demons and deadbeats pour though the veil, ravaging SO quality.  Supernatural creaturs are already a big problem on this plane - best to not give any more non-mundanes air-miles.

Comment: What the heck! -60, that is some kind of a record...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What about [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355870/7605325)?

Comment: @Hugo the idea is even more ridiculous. I just downvoted

Comment: Could it be that I was banned from asking questions because of this thread ?

Comment: @RonTLV Questions bans are [automatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) but the details of the criteria are kept secret. But being massively downvoted surely contributes

Comment: @Hugo seriously ? for feature request !?!?!? I would have never ever imagine the outcome ...

Comment: @RonTLV We can't be sure if only this feature-request is responsible for your ban. I guess it's not enough (but it's just a guess), but as I said, details are not public and we'll never be sure. I've seen an answer some time ago (can't find now, sorry) saying that the criteria are "relaxed" in meta (for the sake of listening different opinions), and the ban can usually occur due to a combination of events in meta and main accounts. Anyway, just one question is probably not enough for a ban, but we can't never be sure...

Comment: @Hugo OK Hugo. Regardless of what you say -  feature requests should be free om punishment !!!!!!! Like it or not I have the right express my opinion, and not only that I feel obliged,

Comment: @RonTLV I'm just saying what I know (and I don't know much about bans, just what I already said). And based on that, I believe that **just this question** is not enough to cause a ban. According to [**FAQ**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/352742): *"internal rules are a secret, but it is **partly** based on downvotes cast by other members of the communities. If the other members of the site consistently give your posts a low ranking, you should try to identify the reason(s) for this"*. And I'm not saying that FR's should be punished (I agree with you about rights to express opinions)

Comment: It took three really annoying, massively-downvoted posts to get rid of the last meta tro... troublemaker.  I doubt that one post will do much, especially as you are not offensive or abusive, merely wrong:)

Comment: @RonTLV https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356026/reasons-for-losing-my-right-to-ask-questions

Answer (score 39):

This is never going to happen.

One person's answerable question is another person's trash. Just because some people answer bad questions does not make them 'good' questions.

We want questions to be useful for future visitors, not just the person asking. Just because you answer a question that doesn't include research, doesn't make that question useful for those future visitors. Voting is there to help others assess the quality of the question, not if the question is on or off topic.

Answer (score 29):

Downvotes are not used to mark questions as "illegitimate".

Rather, they are used to mark questions as:

> does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

(you might recognize that from the tooltip on the downvote arrow)

Questions that are illegitimate or otherwise unacceptable by [our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) are *closed*. Sometimes that is accompanied by downvoting, but not necessarily.

And to preempt your next feature request: no, we should not prevent questions with answers from being closed. Just because someone posts an answer does not, for example, make a question magically on-topic.

Comment: And sometimes, the answer gets upvoted, but the question gets closed/downvoted and deleted, and the rep from the answer is lost. Kind of revenge from high-rep users from answering crap questions in the first place, without downvoting the answer :) I've got candidates questions for that if you ask me.

Answer (score 12):

Bad idea. In a nutshell, my reasons:

- Some questions are bad but can generate good answers (see "reversal" badge). The question remains bad, though.
- The people who answer may not be (and rarely are) the ones who downvote.
- If some newbie posts a bad answer to a bad question, then that would prevent other people to downvote the question, which is still bad.

There's a difference between helping particular people by answering (which may be all right) and improving the quality of the site. Voting on questions is one way to do it and tend to attract good answers/answerers more.

Comment: Side note: if question receives high quality useful answer there is a good chance that "The question remains bad" will not be true for long and post get edited to match SO guidelines.